# Cytoscapejs: How do I prevent rendered subgraphs from zooming out of view?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am rendering graphs of hundreds of nodes, in a directed manner from left to right.

Upon first render, all nodes are in the upper left, and then animate over two seconds to fill my svg box. (fit: true, animate: true, animationDuration: 2000).

One thing I notice is that while expanding, the graph is temporarily larger than my svg box, until it snaps into place. It also appears that the "snapping into place", while still smoothly animated, goes "faster" than the initial animation, even if I have easing set to linear.

But I also have functionality that allows me to (cxtmenu) select a node from the graph, and graph from that node. The rest of the nodes disappear, and then that subgraph animates into place to fill the svg box.

However, the closer to the lower right that node at the root of that subgraph is, the odder the behavior is. If I pick a subgraph close to the lower right, then while it is zooming in, it actually travels further to the lower right at first, even to the point of going entirely off the graph, until it finally zooms (more quickly) back into place in the center of the svg box.

Conceptually, it feels like this has to do with the initial positioning of the subgraph's root node, since it is not at 0,0. It's almost as if the layout algorithm starts first, and then at some point partway through, the fitting/panning algorithm kicks in at a faster rate.

I am having trouble determining how to control/fix this. On an earlier project with dagre and d3 (without cytoscape), I found that similar behavior was because of two competing animation algorithms; one for the layout and one for the zoom/positioning. When I set them to the same duration, they canceled each other out and the animation became smooth.

I am using cytoscape-elkjs. I did try out cytoscape-dagre, and its "boundingbox" option did seem to help, but the elkjs extension doesn't have that, and I am wondering if there's something I can do on the cytoscapejs level to control this.

Comment: Please post your code as a snippet. I don't think I can help, but the chances are significantly higher if you show us your current status